# Foreign keys referencing superkeys

Tags: database, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

As far as I know, foreign keys can reference candidate keys of tables. Can a compound foreign key also reference a superkey of a table (in case overdefinition is required)? If possible I am interested in how it could be done in mysql workbench.